# Is there a conjugate prior for Gumbel-distributed data?

Tags: bayesian, conjugate-prior, gumbel-distribution

I am trying to fit a Gumbel distribution to a set of N i.i.d. data points. I was wondering whether there is a conjugate prior to infer the two parameters of the Gumbel pdf.

Comment: Yes, there is a conjugate prior for the parameters of the Gumbel distribution. Unfortunately it is not simple. You can find it in this [paper](http://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1081/STA-100002093).

Comment: That's your answer.